# Scrapy / XPATH : how to extract ONLY text from descendants and self

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I have the following simple, nested structure:

```
<main>
    <em>bla-bla</em>

    <div class="1">1.1</div>

    <div class="2">2.1</div>

    <div class="2">2.2</div>

    <div class="1">1.2</div>

    <div class="2">
        <span>
            <em>2.3</em>
        </span>
    </div>

    <div class="2">2.4</div>

</main>
```

I would like to extract now all text from all  nodes, but struggle with the nested node ( etc.).

The expected output should be:

```
2.1
2.2
2.3
2.4
```

Trying something like:

```
//div[contains(@class,"2")]/text()
```

gives

```
2.1
2.2
<div class="2"><span><em>2.3</em></span></div>
<div class="2"><span><em>2.3</em></span></div>
2.4
```

Instead of using straight XPATH, I also tried using several steps in Scrapy, like:

```
divs = response.xpath("//div[contains(@class,"2")]")

for div in divs:
   # now check somehow that the div contains an "em" node
```

Using

```
div.xpath("//em")
```

does not work, since it gives all  nodes. Using div.extract() here and looking at the returned string, I could of course find  using string search, but this is rather a hack and does not look like the proper Scrapy solution.

Any suggestions how to solve this either directly with Xpath or with Scrapy in general would be grealy appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you think about `[i.strip() for i in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "2")]//text()').extract() if i.strip()]`?

Without stripping it gives some empty cases also:

```
>>> response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "2")]//text()').extract()
[u'2.1', u'2.2', u'\n        ', u'\n            ', u'2.3', u'\n        ', u'\n    ', u'2.4']
```

So I filter them with `strip`:

```
>>> [i.strip() for i in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class, "2")]//text()').extract() if i.strip()]
[u'2.1', u'2.2', u'2.3', u'2.4']
```